# unable to connect to python server running on windows from android client

Tags: java, android, windows, sockets, network-programming

I've a python server running on windows platform and an android client connects to it. I hard coded the `ip` of server running on windows( obtained from properties of `wifi` connected and labelled with `IPv4 address`) in the android client along with the server port. However everytime i'm getting connection timeout error (tried from two different android devices).
To ensure whether the `ip` of the server is correct I ping this `ip` on the windows machine itself and succeeded but still getting connection timeout when tried connecting android client to it. so I checked whether the port is opened or not, with command `telnet <ip> <port>` and it fails. The only thing i can conclude from it that `ip` is incorrect as when I replaced it with `localhost(127.0.0.1)` it successfully pings the port.

Am I missing something here? Is the above a correct way to get IP address to be able to connect to it from other devices.
android phone and windows machine is connected to same network(I mean laptop/windows-machine is connected to the phone's hotspot).

**UPD**: I just tried to ping the server from my android phone and it fails.

**android studio logs:**

```
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.43.153 (port 9998) from /:: (port 57996): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:143)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:142)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:390)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:230)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:212)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:436)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:631)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:571)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:451)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:251)
W/System.err:     at com.example.audio_call.createRoom$1.run(createRoom.java:78)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
    Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
        at libcore.io.Linux.connect(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:136)
        at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.connect(ForwardingOs.java:95)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:157)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:135)
        ... 11 more
D/testing error message: failed to connect to /192.168.43.153 (port 9998) from /:: (port 57996): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

**Output of ipconfig/all**(executed on command prompt)

```
 Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 88-B1-11-22-80-AD
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%XX(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%XX(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%XX(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.153(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 19 May 2021 05:01:47
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 19 May 2021 08:01:51
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX%XX
                                       192.168.43.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXXXXXX
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.43.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

**server code**:

```
class TCPMainServer(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        print("Server created/started")
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = recv(self.request, decode= False).decode("utf-8")
        data = self.data.split()
        print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 9998  #Server address and port
    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9998
    with socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), TCPMainServer) as server:       
        # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
        # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
        server.serve_forever()
```

`recv` has a separate implementation which extract the actual payload from whole stream.

Comment: Where is your Android client running?

Comment: So there is a Windows machine, a laptop and an Android phone?

Comment: It is unclear how you determined ip and of which device.

Comment: @blackapps laptop is the windows machine. android client is the mobile phone on which the application which connects to the server on windows is running.

Comment: @blackapps ip of server/windows machine .

Comment: What kind of server is it? And how does the client try to connect?

Comment: It's a simple python based server implementation. a port(9998) is opened on which it listens to requests.

Comment: client is just an android application here which tries to connect to server using `Socket socket = new socket(host, 9998)`.

Comment: `new Socket(192.168.43.153, 9998)`? Please show the python server code

Comment: added. Please see.

Comment: @blackapps yes. new Socket(192.168.43.153, 9998) is there in client side code. .

Comment: are you using same android device to ping which also has the hotspot? if yes then it will not work you need to make hotspot on a separate phone and so that android phone and laptop are on same network.

Comment: `# Create the server, binding to localhost` Well that you should not do. Why to 127.0.0.1? Then a client from another device can not connect as you have seen. A server should do nothing with ip's. Does not have to know ip's. Just open the port. Do nothing with an ip. And certainly do not bind to an ip.

Comment: @EhsanWaris For now yes. But i tried it both ways on two different devices. second device  i tested with  and the laptop was connected to the hotspot created by first device. and btw, why it will not  be on same network in this case?

Comment: @blackapps ok let me try this too. Hope it works, it has taken a lot of time by now. but i still don't understand why it will not work.

Comment: @user14610638 in my experience the device that creates hotspot is not itself connected to that hotspot.

Comment: Because if you bind to 127.0.0.1 only clients with that ip can connect. Hence only clients that run on that laptop.

Comment: but isn't the mobile data and the hotspot created by it are same network??

Comment: and what about the mobile not being able to ping `192.168.43.153` ??

Comment: mobile data (cellular network) and hotspot are two different networks, you'll only be able to ping a static IP using mobile data. whereas hotspot is your local network and if both devices are connected to same hotspot you'll able to ping them.